# How to convert Rowset to Uni<int[]> in quarkus?

Tags: java, vert.x, quarkus

As I am new to quarkus, I have been stuck at place, here I am fetching all the ids from database but I am not able to return it as Uni<int[]>, please help me out.

```
public Uni<int[]> getRun(String owner, Date dateIN) {
    try{
        sql="select r.id from tabel r where r.userName=$1 AND (r.endDate IS NULL OR r.endDate >=$2)";
    
        return client.preparedQuery(sql).execute(Tuple.of(owner,dateIN)).onItem().transform(pgRowSet -> pgRowSet.iterator())
        .onItem().transform(ro -> ro.hasNext() ? Integer.parseInt(ro.next().toString()) : 0);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here I am not able to return it as Uni<int[]>, query other things are working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public Uni<int[]> getRun(String owner, Date dateIN) {
    String sql = "select r.id from tabel r where r.userName=$1 AND (r.endDate IS NULL OR r.endDate >=$2)";
    return client.preparedQuery(sql).execute(Tuple.of(owner, dateIN)).onItem().transform(rows -> {
        return StreamSupport.stream(rows.spliterator(), false).mapToInt(row -> row.getInteger(0)).toArray();
    });
}
```